# Conditional Series Fill in R

Tags: r, time-series

Looking for a way to fill in a vector with new values conditional on values within that vector and another variable in the data frame. Pasted an example of what the data looks like below.

```
PrsVar= c(rep(1,10),rep(2,7),rep(3,11))
IndVar = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
OutVar = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)
exampdata <- cbind(PrsVar,IndVar,OutVar)
exampdata <- as.data.frame(exampdata)

> exampdata
   PrsVar IndVar OutVar
1       1      0      1
2       1      0      1
3       1      0      1
4       1      1      1
5       1      0      2
6       1      0      2
7       1      1      2
8       1      0      3
9       1      0      3
10      1      0      3
11      2      0      1
12      2      0      1
13      2      0      1
14      2      1      1
15      2      0      2
16      2      0      2
17      2      1      2
18      3      0      1
19      3      0      1
20      3      0      1
21      3      1      1
22      3      0      2
23      3      0      2
24      3      0      2
25      3      1      2
26      3      0      3
27      3      0      3
28      3      0      3
```

This is time-series data and each row represents a person-day. `PrsVar` is an ID for an individual in the study and `IndVar` is an indicator that an episode has ended on that person-day. The person-day after that represents a new episode.

I'd like to create a variable that looks like `OutVar` using just the values from `PrsVar` and `IndVar`. This new variable `OutVar` labels the episode each person-day is in, incrementing by 1, and starting over at 1 for each new individual.

I could run this through a loop, but I need more efficient code to work with 3,000,000+ rows of data. Was trying to use something in `dplyr` or maybe `mapply`, but I'm stumped. Thinking a solution to this would be helpful to others and would certainly be helpful to me again in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit ugly, but this logic should be easily adaptable to other methods:

```
with(exampdata,
  ave(IndVar, PrsVar, FUN=function(x) {
    out <- rev(cumsum(rev(x)))
    max(out) - out + 1
  })
)

# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this. Wasn't thinking about the reverse, reverse, very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The `data.table` package offers a fast, efficient, and tidy way to do this. It's all done by reference (not by value, so no copying is done) so millions of rows won't be an issue at all (under a minute, maybe).

```
library(data.table)
patient.data <- data.table(PrsVar = c(rep(1,10), rep(2,7), rep(3,11)),
                           IndVar = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),
                           OutVar = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3))
```

Increment an episode counter `EpVar` based on the cumulative sum of `IndVar` (plus `1`). This increases the counter at the record where `IndVar` increases (which is too early) so shift it down a record with `shift`, replacing the missing value with a reset counter (`1`). This can be done groupwise with the `by` keyword.

```
patient.data[ , EpVar:=shift(1+cumsum(IndVar), fill=1), by=PrsVar]
patient.data
    PrsVar IndVar OutVar EpVar
 1:      1      0      1     1
 2:      1      0      1     1
 3:      1      0      1     1
 4:      1      1      1     1
 5:      1      0      2     2
 6:      1      0      2     2
 7:      1      1      2     2
 8:      1      0      3     3
 9:      1      0      3     3
10:      1      0      3     3
11:      2      0      1     1
12:      2      0      1     1
13:      2      0      1     1
14:      2      1      1     1
15:      2      0      2     2
16:      2      0      2     2
17:      2      1      2     2
18:      3      0      1     1
19:      3      0      1     1
20:      3      0      1     1
21:      3      1      1     1
22:      3      0      2     2
23:      3      0      2     2
24:      3      0      2     2
25:      3      1      2     2
26:      3      0      3     3
27:      3      0      3     3
28:      3      0      3     3
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been thinking of using data.table, but haven't had time to get into it and dplyr on data frames has been going fairly well.

Comment: If you're looking to learn `data.table`, the DataCamp course is well structured. `dplyr` works on data.tables too. The speed improvement due to copy by reference is outstanding and when using millions of rows, potentially necessary.

The `dplyr` on `data.frame` version of my answer still requires `data.table::shift()` but is more or less the same;

    `library(dplyr); data.frame(patient.data) %>% group_by(PrsVar) %>% mutate(EpVar=shift(1 + cumsum(IndVar), fill = 1))`